# Is an inserted element’s connectedCallback guaranteed to run before the callback of a MutationObserver observing it?

Tags: javascript, custom-element, mutation-observers

Let’s say I’m inserting a custom element `<my-element></my-element>` into a page and there is a MutationObserver observing the parent element for `childList` mutations.

In my testing, the `connectedCallback` of the inserted custom element always fires before the MutationObserver’s callback.

This makes sense, and is what I expect.

What I’d like to know is, is there any way to know that this is guaranteed to always be the case? Is it safe to assume that these callbacks will always fire in this order?

```js
const hostEl = document.getElementById('host');
const templateEl = document.getElementById('async-element');
const asyncElementEl = templateEl.content.cloneNode(true);

const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    const elementsInMutation = Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).filter(
      (node) => node.nodeType === 1
    );
    for (const el of elementsInMutation) {
      console.log(Date.now(), 'observed mutation, inserted:', el);
    }
  }
});

mutationObserver.observe(hostEl, {
  childList: true,
});

if (!customElements.get('my-element')) {
  class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      console.log(Date.now(), 'connectedCallback', this);
    }
  }

  customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)
}

console.log(Date.now(), 'inserting async element');
templateEl.before(asyncElementEl);
```

```html
<main id="host">
  <template id="async-element">
    <my-element><div>Hello</div></my-element>
  </template>
</main>
```

Comment: Judging by [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#creating-and-inserting-nodes), calling "custom element reactions" is an inner part of a node's creation-and-insertion step, whereas reporting a mutation is not, i.e. it always happens afterwards.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, happy to make this the accepted answer if you want to post it as an answer